# Why can't I get an Internet connection with Wifi Pineapple Nano?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet

I am new to wifi pineapple. I am having a problem with my wifi pineapple nano for windows 10. I followed the initial setup of nano for windows and I am not getting any internet connection.

When I click the "Load Bulletins" from Dashboard, I get the error:

> "Error connecting to WiFiPineapple.com. Please check your connection."

I have attached the images for my network setting and the error I am getting. I have even tried it without the Default Gateway value: 172.16.42.1 but it still does not work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Error seen on the home page of wifi pineapple nano:

[image: error seen on the home page of wifi pineapple nano]

My computer network settings:

[image: my computer network settings]

Answer (score 0):

My Windows 10 setup is working with this config (as per their video) using firmware 1.1.1:

`IP address: 172.16.42.42
Subnet mask: 255.255.0.0` note your subnet mask is wrong
`Default gateway:` blank

`Obtain DNS server address automatically` - should be checked

That said, Windows 10 just wouldn't make the connection work. I tried repeated rebooting, rechecking, and repeating setup. Finally it (Load bulletins) worked but I don't know why it decided to do so.